# How to Color code td element of HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

I need to dynamically color code certain columns of table bases on figures in the cell. I want first 4 rows to be formatted if they are more than 3 but all next rows should be formatted if figure in it is more than 1.

I want to format alternate columns of table if for first 4 rows cell values is more than 3. 5th row onwards i want to format if cell value is more than 1. I am using below javascript but that gives me all the rows formatting with 1.

```
 $(function() {
        $("td:nth-child(3),td:nth-child(5),td:nth-child(7),td:nth-child(9),td:nth-child(11)").each(function()
          {
            var score = parseFloat($(this).text());
            if (score >= '1.00')
            {
           $(this).addClass('good');
            }
            else if (score < '-0.99')
            {
           $(this).addClass('good');
            }
        })
 })
```

Comment: You have converted score to number but compare it with a string. Why?
You should compare same types, otherwise the automatic type conversion would take place as in your case.

Comment: So, what's in your table cells? I'd guess that they contain something which can't be parsed to floating point number and that's why you have this outcome.

Comment: thanks factor5 My cell has % value rounded to 2 decimals. The above code is working fine if i had to just compare for 1 % but i also want to compare first 4 rows to check 3%

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is to add styles to the table cells when the following conditions are met:

- For the first four rows, style the odd number column cells if the value is greater than or equal to 3
- For the fifth row and beyond, style the odd number column cells if the value is greater than or equal to 1

Then, you can add a class to the  element for the first four rows like this: `<tr class="firstFourRows">`

For the javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        (function () {
            /*
             *  choose either one (start)
             */
            // if you CAN modify the HTML
            // this selector select the first four tr elements with odd number column cells
            $('.firstFourRows > td:nth-of-type(2n + 3)').each(function () {
                var score = parseFloat($(this).text());

                if (score >= 3) {
                    $(this).addClass('good');
                }
            });

            // if you CANNOT modify the HTML
            for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
                $('tr:nth-child(' + i + ') > td:nth-of-type(2n + 3)').each(function () {
                    var score = parseFloat($(this).text());

                    if (score >= 3) {
                        $(this).addClass('good');
                    }
                });
            }

            /*
             *  choose either one (end)
             */

            // this selector select the fifth row and beyond with odd number column cells
            $('tr:nth-child(n + 5) > td:nth-of-type(2n + 3)').each(function () {
                var score = parseFloat($(this).text());

                if (score >= 1) {
                    $(this).addClass('good');
                }
            });
        }());
    });
```

Comment: Hi @Ray Chan Thanks for reply. But my table is dynamically created with python script. That is why i can not add tr class <tr class="firstFourRows">. This is actually monthly report. If today is 5th of the month then table will show only 5 rows and so on so forth. I want to show % column in color format if first rows are more than 3% and 5th onward more than 1%. Can you suggest any solution for it.

Comment: I updated the answer, please let me know if it solves your problem.